# Cannot print from LibreOffice, but can from a terminal

Tags: 18.04, printing, libreoffice, canon

I was successful in installing the driver and packages provided by Canon. I can see the printer's name when I try to print something in LibreOffice. I used the `lpr` command to print in terminal to check. After using a string of letters and closing the terminal, it finally printed in terminal.

What is the issue? What extra information I can provide you?

This is what I have after fiddling around with the canon download (url is in the comment):

[image: screenshot]

Oddly, after being able to move to the software center by way of the icon, now I cannot (I had clicked on launch before), but nothing.

[image: screenshot of software center]

Comment: `lpstat -t` output?

Comment: scheduler is running
system default destination: LBP6030-6040-6018L
device for CUPS-BRF-Printer: cups-brf:/
device for LBP6030-6040-6018L: usb://Canon/LBP6030/6040/6018L?serial=0000A3FAAABQ
CUPS-BRF-Printer accepting requests since ven. 31 janv. 2020 20:36:47 +07
LBP6030-6040-6018L accepting requests since sam. 01 févr. 2020 16:13:49 +07
printer CUPS-BRF-Printer is idle.  enabled since ven. 31 janv. 2020 20:36:47 +07
printer LBP6030-6040-6018L is idle.  enabled since sam. 01 févr. 2020 16:13:49 +07

Comment: I followed most of the instructions here (https://oip.manual.canon/USRMA-0593-zz-DR-enGB/contents/dlu-status-int.html#main_06_01), although I did fiddle around using other instructions before which might have led to some issues. Some of the commands do not respond like the print command with the model number attached.

Comment: I just noticed that I have an icon canon utility that was placed on my app pane. I clicked on it, but nothing. I managed to go to the software center and tried to launch it there, but nothing. I have the printer on and usb connected.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by using the information I provided in the comments. The final step that made it all work was going into settings, printer and, by selecting the printer, adding it. I had my printer plugged in with the usb connection too. It worked on LibreOffice when I selected that same printer (I had 2 [a generic and the one with the actual real name). I hope this can help someone with the same issue. Thanks to all who tried to help.