# Printer works but docs can only print to file

Tags: 20.04, printing

I am a total Newbie with Ubuntu 20.04. My printer is printing o.k. from pfs, web pages, etc. But with docs, Libreoffice it will not print at all, and with docs OnlyOffice it will only 'print to file'.
Cannot change the print dialog box.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1207281/75166)

Comment: @MadMike But that question doesn't have a good answer , So this question isn't bad.

Comment: @AkshajSingla yeah, the linked answer doesn't have a accepted answer. But I would still prefer to close this one as duplicate and accept the answer there.

Comment: @MadMike But I don't think that answer is so helpful

Comment: @AkshajSingla I agree that the answer isn't very good. I've opened a [meta-question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19780/75166) to resolve it.

Comment: @MadMike Cool , That's nice , I agree to it

Comment: Eight responses about closing the question. Zero responses to help the user. Typical askubuntu.com/. OnlyOffice  is irrelevant. It is not shipped with Ubuntu.

Comment: Well, thanks all for the 'not so useful comments'. I didn't realize that it was the same as another question had I understood that I would have not posted. As I said, I am new to Linux, never used it before and know absolutely nothing about it, but willing to learn. It would be helpful if you had a little more patience. Sorry.
@brian_p, thank you, I am just using LibreOffice now and I am saving to pdf then printing from there. This may not be right, but for now......

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the fact that OnlyOffice is usually installed via snap in Ubuntu.

Please refer to [lepe](https://askubuntu.com/users/8747/lepe)'s [post about Inkscape](https://askubuntu.com/a/1128182), which I'm quoting below:

> It's not a bug. Snaps run in containers with separate environments which prevent applications to access all the system (as the classic applications do) for security. By default printers are not accessible, but can be enabled with:
>
> ```
> sudo snap connect inkscape:cups-control :cups-control
> ```
>
> That will allow printers to show in Inkscape. Change `inskcape` for the name of the application (for example, `gimp`) if needed.
> It happened to me with WPS Office: [this was my question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083698/wps-office-has-not-found-any-installed-printers).
>
> You need to restart the application to take effect.

In my personal opinion, it would be nice if during installation you could specify such permissions or that the applications could decide which permissions requires and let the user know about them (like Android applications).

Pretty much the same solution works for OnlyOffice. And no, the initial question is not a duplicate of the one about printing problems in LibreOffice.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with OnlyOffice, my solution was to start terminal then remove the package and re-install it.
I have had problems installing software from 'Ubuntu Software' previously and used the same fix for that.